# Put files to cloud from multer node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud, multer

What i am trying to do:

- save file to local temp storage
- send it to cloud storage
- resive url from cloud
- save to database this url

**First save file to local temp storage**

```
router.post('/', auth, upload.single('file'), async(req, res) => {
    try {
        if(req.file === undefined)
            return res.status(400).send({ error: 'File object is undefined' });

        // upload to cloud
        const cloudFile = await putFile(req.file);

        return res.status(201).send(cloudFile);
    } catch(e) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Cant save file', message: e.message });
    }
});
```

that works fine

**Then put it to cloud**

```
const putFile = async (file) => {
    const auth = await getAuthToken();
    const formData = new FormData();

    const fileBuffer = await fs.readFileSync(file.path, 'utf8', (error, buffer) => ({ error, buffer }));

    if(fileBuffer.error)
        return { ...file, error: fileBuffer.error };

    formData.append('file', fileBuffer);

    return await axios.put(auth['x-storage-url'], formData, {
        headers: {
            'X-Auth-Token': auth['x-auth-token'],
            ...formData.getHeaders()
        }
    })
        .then(() => {
            file.src = auth['x-storage-url'] + '/' + file.filename;

            fs.unlink(file.path);

            return file;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            throw new Error(e.message);
        });
};
```

it works **BUT** when i try to get file as `https://...cloudUrl.../filename` it's crashed!

Looks like `readFileSync` doesn't read file properly and there is no error at `fileBuffer.error`

Do you have any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're not reading the file correctly as you're mixing `async/await` and a callback in a synchronous method call. You were probably intending to do:

```
try {
  const fileBuffer = await fs.promises.readFile(file.path, 'utf8');
  // rest of the code
} catch(err) {
  // handle err
}
```